# Limited access Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I am currently working with the Galleria js Slider.

I need callback to event when a user tries to view slide images 6>

I want to bar users from seeing slide 6 and above and display a popup when he clicks on 6> thumbnails or the forward arrow.

Apologies for my poor Engish.

Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

---

I've tried

```
    var gallery = Galleria.get(0);

    gallery.bind("loadfinish", function(e) {
        if (e.index > 5) {
            myCallback();

            return false; // Here I need to prevent image showing
        }            
    });
```

---

Solution:

```
    var selector = '#galleria-1';
    Galleria.run(selector);

    $(selector).data('galleria').bind('loadfinish', function(e) {
            if(e.index > 4) { // > the fifth image
                $(selector +' .galleria-image img').css('opacity', 0);
                this.show( 0 );

                myCallback();
            }
    })
```

Comment: "I am ... I need ... I want" so now just do `:)` Seriously, please post what you have tried

Comment: I have posted my attempts

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Galleria.on('loadstart', function(e) {
    if(e.index == 5) {
        alert('6th image!');
    }
})
```

http://galleria.io/docs/api/events/#loadstart

Comment: thank you. It is good for callback. I tried to use "event.stopImmediatePropagation()" in this callback to prevent image loading but it doesn't work.

Comment: and if I have more than one gallery on single page can I get Gallery object by selector or something like that: var galleryObject = Galleria.run('#galleria-1'); I found only var gallery = Galleria.get(0);